# ZSH Quote escaping and expansion

Tags: command-line, zsh, tmux

I am trying to run tmux, passing several commands at once, and I'm unable to properly quote the string.

The command succeeds when manually entered on the command line:

```
~% /usr/local/bin/tmux start-server\; set-option -g default-command '/usr/bin/true 1 2 3' \; new-session
[exited]
```

But in the real case, I need to build the command dynamically, and then I'm unable to get it to expand correctly. The single quotes seem to get discarded during the `${=var}` expansion:

```
 ~% cmd="/usr/local/bin/tmux start-server; set-option -g default-command '/usr/bin/true 1 2 3' ; new-session"
 ~% ${=cmd}
usage: set-option [-agosquw] [-t target-session|target-window] option [value]
```

tmux doesn't understand the command when passed as a single string, i.e. not including the `/usr/local/bin/tmux` token in the string, and expanding the rest using `${cmd}` as opposed to `${=cmd}`.

```
~% /usr/local/bin/tmux 'start-server; set-option -g default-command "/usr/bin/true 1 2 3"; new-session'
unknown command: start-server; set-option -g default-command "/usr/bin/true 1 2 3"; new-session
```

my zsh version:

```
⚠~% ${SHELL} --version
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1)
```

Answer (score 3):

`${(z)var}` expands the variable while keeping the inner quotes intact.